# Returning value from two methods in java

Tags: java, methods

I use a method

```
public String introduce()
{
   return super.introduce();

}
```

which returns the value from `introduce()` method of super class. And assume `introduce()` method returns

> Hey! I'm Steve and I'm 26 years old

In the same class,I also have another method

```
public String getAlter() {
    return alter;
}
```

Now  `alter` contains the value:

> Jobs

Now, the question is how do I return the value

> Hey! I'm Steve and I'm 26 years old. I'm also known as Jobs!

from the overridden method, ie

```
public String introduce()
{
   return super.introduce();

}
```

Comment: Where is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: @DaDaDom The question is obviously "How do I return the super value plus an additional value?"

Comment: So this was a long way of asking how to concat strings in Java?

Comment: Keep in mind that we, the folks with the answers, know what "concat" means. The author may not. If I knew the word for everything I wanted to know, I'd end up here far less often. I don't see a problem with the clarity of the question - only (maybe) the amount of research effort.

Answer (score 8):

Just concatinate the strings returned by the two methods:

```
@Override
public String introduce() {
   return super.introduce() + ". I'm also known as " + getAlter() + "!";

}
```

Comment: `String.format` would be a better choice, but this is the correct answer.

Comment: I find `+` must easier to read. The performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @sdgfsdh maybe in beginner projects and toy projects. But it is a good habit to get into - _templating_. The earlier we get beginners into separating their output formats from their inputs the less dodgy HTML/SQL concatenation we will find in production code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the method introduce:

1) call the super class method introduce() -> returns "Hey! I'm Steve and I'm 26 years old"
2) use method getAlter() inside the overridden method introduce()"

```
public String getAlter() {
    return "Jobs";
}

@Override
public String introduce() {
    String msg = super.introduce();
    String name = this.getAlter();
    msg = msg + ". I'm also known as " + name + "!";

    return msg;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jobs jobs = new Jobs();
    String msg = jobs.introduce();
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String introduce()
{
   return super.introduce()+" I'm also known as "+getAlter();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of `super.introduce()` to build your final result.

```
@Override
public String introduce() {
    return super.introduce() + ". I'm also known as " + getAlter() + "!";
}
```

Note the `@Override` annotation to make it clear that I am hiding the super implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't immediately return your call to `super`:

```
public String introduce()
{
   return super.introduce() + getAlter();

   // for clarity, you are essentially performing these operations:
   // String response = super.introduce();
   // response = response + " I'm also known as ";
   // response = response + getAlter();
   // return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to append them like:

```
@Override
public String introduce() {
   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   strBuilder.append(super.introduce());
   strBuilder.append(" I'm also known as");
   strBuilder.append(getAlter());

   return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: There seems very little reason to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Boris. It's just the way I often implement in my code. :)